# Why doesn't Swift nil-coalescing ternary operator return unwrapped type?

Tags: swift, conditional-operator

I read that the ternary operator `??` unwraps an optional if it is not nil, but if I do:

```
var type: String?
type = "milk"
let certainType = type ?? "melon"
```

then certainType will still be a `String?`, and if I do

```
println("it's a \(certainType)")
```

it will print:

```
it's a Optional("milk")
```

Thoughts?

Update:

Sorry for the confusion - I meant var type: String?

I get that it should print "it's a milk", but what I saw in console is a "it's a Optional("milk")" - anyone else experienced the same issue? Could that be caused by string interpolation?

Asked by @Antonio, here is more context and real code and logging snapshot - type is from Note, which is a NSManagedObject class used to deal with xcdatamodel

```
class Note: NSManagedObject {
  @NSManaged var type: String?
}
```

And I have the type set to 'todo' at some point, then have the following code to print them out:

```
println("type class:\(_stdlib_getDemangledTypeName(note.type))")
let type1 = note.type ?? "note"
println("type1:\(type1)")
let type2: String = note.type ?? "note"
println("type2:\(type2)")
```

And the output:

```
type class:Swift.Optional
type1:Optional("todo")
type2:todo
```

As you can see, if I don't explicitly mark the type1's type as String, it will print undesired result Optional("todo") - I use the type in a string interpolation to construct a path so it matters

Comment: It would be nice to see the actual compiling code...

Comment: I am guessing the real code the questioner is looking at (as opposed to the non-compiling code they typed in) is either a case where `type` is a `String??` or `”melon”` is actually a variable of type `String?`.  In either case,  `String?? ?? String` and `String? ?? String?` both evaluate to `String?` (though for different reasons).  `String ?? String?` does too.

Comment: @hyouuu: even after fixing that error, your code still prints the expected result `"it's a milk"`. The only case it shows the unexpected message `it's a Optional("milk")` is when you declare the `type` variable as `String??`.

Comment: Interesting - I actually haven't read anything about the ?? type - what does it do? I didn't declare String??, but could it because it was a NSManagedObject from Core Data? The type is defined as "  @NSManaged var type: String?"

Comment: @hyouuu that's an `Optional<Optional<String>>` - you can think of it as a double optional, or an optional which can contain either nil or an optional string, which in turn can contain either nil or a string. I think you should show us the real code to figure out what's going on

Comment: @Antonio thanks more context added

Comment: From the future: it's mid 2016, and I pasted the first 3 lines here into "xcrun swift", and it works fine (no "Optional" in the output), so I guess it was a bug that got fixed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The OP asserts that code similar to this:

```
var type: String? = "milk"
let certainType = type ?? "melon"
println("it's a \(certainType)")
```

prints an unexpected string:

> "it's a Optional("milk")"

whereas it should be:

> "it's a milk"

It turns out that happens when the variable is actually a property with the `@NSManaged` attribute.

I suspect that there is a bug in type inference. The OP states that:

```
let certainType = type ?? "melon"
```

prints the wrong result, whereas:

```
let certainType: String = type ?? "melon"
```

prints the correct one.

So *for some reason, without explicitly indicating the variable type, the nil coalescing operator is returning an optional*.

**If I change the type of the `type` variable to either `AnyObject` or `AnyObject?`, it actually prints the *unexpected* result**:

```
var type: AnyObject = "milk"
let certainType = type ?? "melon"
println("it's a \(certainType)")
```

> "it's a Optional(milk)"

My guess is: *because the `@NSManaged` attribute is used, the property is inferred with the wrong type (`AnyObject?`) when used, unless the correct type is explicitly indicated*.

As to why that happens, no idea (besides thinking it's a bug)

Comment: Thanks for the finding! I feel it is the right explanation to the issue - it's likely a @NSManaged bug, or I'm using it not properly (probably should use AnyObject? instead of String? for the property for the time being, which would be a lame implementation of NSManaged stuff in Swift). Either way this explains the case where the weird situation happens. Any more thoughts from others are appreciated.

Answer (score 3):

This is (I think) by design. If you do this:

```
let type = "mil"
println("it's a \(type)")
```

If I am not mistaken, this will print `it's a "milk"` which is far more useful when debugging than `it's a String`. Note that `\(...)` is similar to `%@` in Objective-C: classes can override their string representation.

Also, as Antonio already pointed out:

1. You cannot change an immutable variable (i.e. a `let`).
2. Optional let variables therefore are useless (i.e. don't do `let type: String? = "milk"` because it clearly is never going to be nil).

Comment: Sorry edited! It is printing out "it's a Optional("milk")" not "it's a milk" for me :(

Answer (score 3):

> I read that the ternary operator ?? unwraps an optional if it is not nil, but...

It does unwrap it.

> let type: String?
>   type = "milk"
>   let certainType = type ?? "melon"

Your code won't compile, but if you change the let to var, it will work and certainType will be of type String.

```
var type: String?
type = "milk"
let certainType = type ?? "melon"

println("it's a \(certainType)") // prints "it's a milk"
```

Comment: Sorry edited! It is printing out "it's a Optional("milk")" not "it's a milk" for me :( –  hyouuu just now   edit

Answer (score 2):

This is known as the [Nil Coalescing Operator](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Swift/Conceptual/Swift_Programming_Language/BasicOperators.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40014097-CH6-ID72).

If you have an Optional `a`, the result of  `a ?? b` will be `a!` if `a` is not `nil` and `b` if it is. It's shorthand for this expression:

```
a != nil ? a! : b
```

So, you are using the operator correctly, but you must initialize a constant on the same line that you declare it:

```
let type: String? = "milk"
```

However, I'm assuming that you don't want that to be a constant in this context (since you're checking what it is), so if you use `var` to declare it, your existing code should work.

Answer (score 1):

I was having a similar problem.

I have a dictionary of type `[String : AnyObject]`, but the entry I was after turns out to be a `String` value. Fearing it may not always be present. I was retrieving it with the following code:

```
let message = dictionary["message"] ?? "No message"
```

However, when the entry is present, that would still give the string:

> Optional(the actual message)

i.e., the variable `message` is of type `String?`.

I changed it to:

```
let message = (dictionary["message"] as? String) ?? "No message"
```

...and now the retrieved value is an unwrapped, non-optional string.

Answer (score 0):

This is what you want

```
let certainType = type! ?? "melon"
```

Notice I unwrapped type.  It works when you:

```
let type2: String = note.type ?? "note"
```

because you are essentially unwrapping in your cast to String.

Answer (score 0):

The issue in my case was `@NSManaged` attribute of type `NSNumber?` that I was trying to wrap in a string.

`let time = "\(nsManagedObject.optionalNsNumber ?? "") months"
/// result "Optional(<random number>) months"`

The solution to this issue was to convert `NSNumber` to `stringValue`. Below is the code that worked as expected.

`let time = "\(nsManagedObject.optionalNsNumber.stringValue ?? "") months"
/// result "<random number> months"`

Swift compiler will not spot the issue if the value is wrapped in a string. If you try to use `nil coalescing` operator then add the result to a string it will point to the error at hand, `Can't add NSObject and String`.

Be careful when wrapping `@NSManaged` attributes into strings.

Answer (score 0):

I found one way have a try.

```
infix operator ???


/// use this custom operator to overcome issue related to '??' which always needs assignment to remove Optional
///
/// - parameter lhs: left hand side variable
/// - parameter rhs: right hand side variable
///
/// - returns: it will return unwrapped value of one of the variable which has not nil value
func ???(lhs: Any?, rhs: Any?) -> Any {

    let temp : Any = lhs ?? rhs

    return temp

}
```